# Safe method call to log common Exception using Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am working on a project which have couple of method calls sequentially one after the other. These are the external calls.

Pseudo code depicting the similar behavior:

```
void calls() {
    add(Integer:a, Integer:b);
    multiply(BigDecimal:a, BigDecimal:b);
    sub(Float:a, Float:b);
    areaOfSquare(Integer: a);
}
```

Any of the above method throwing exception will skip all the below methods.
So, individual methods can be wrapped in a try/catch block. But it's not a clean code.

```
try {
    add(Integer:a, Integer:b);
} catch(Exception e) {}
try {
     multiply(BigDecimal:a, BigDecimal:b);
} catch(Exception e) {}
try {
     sub(Float:a, Float:b);
} catch(Exception e) {}
try {
     areaOfSquare(Integer: a);
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

I am planning to write a safeCall method which abstracts the exception inside the safeCall method. Thereby callers don't have to worry about exception logging.
I am unable to come up on how to construct the safeCall method.

```
void calls() {
        safeCall(() -> add(Integer:a, Integer:b));
        safeCall(() -> multiply(BigDecimal:a, BigDecimal:b));
        safeCall(() -> sub(Float:a, Float:b));
        safeCall(() -> areaOfSquare(Integer: a));
    }

private void safeCall(Supplier<?> function) {
    try {
        function.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Are you really planning to ignore exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the Supplier interface to void

Catch any exceptions thrown by method invocation inside the safeCall() method, `log them` and then `again throw the Runtime exception`

The main idea is to use reflection to obtain the corresponding method and invoke it, passing the arguments to safeCall. If an exception occurs, it is logged and then `rethrown as a RuntimeException to interrupt the execution` of subsequent methods

You can modify your safeCall like this:

```java
private void safeCall(String methodName, Object... args) {
    try {
        Method method = getClass().getMethod(methodName, getParameterTypes(args));
        method.invoke(this, args);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log exception with "methodName" and args
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); // Throw exception again as RuntimeException
    }
}

private Class<?>[] getParameterTypes(Object... args) {
    if (args == null)
        return new Class<?>[0];
    
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        parameterTypes[i] = args[i].getClass();
    
    return parameterTypes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. we are not adding Java reflection in application code. Do you suggest any other ways apart from reflection?

Comment: You can use a higher-order function or lambda expression instead of using reflection:
interface CheckedSupplier<T> {
    T get() throws Exception;
}

private void safeCall(CheckedSupplier<?> function) {
    try {
        function.get();
    } catch (Exception eч) {
        // log the exception
    }
}